# Any body know how we can use this EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider package from nuget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, plugins, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to separate my views, controllers and models in a separate DLL and then load them into my host application. When i Google it i found this `EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider` or `VirtualPathProvider` may be the way we can do it but unfortunately not found any working sample application or may be anything else which can fulfill this requirement in a good way please let me know. I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with razor view engine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you try it yourself and then ask questions about problems that you run into. StackOverflow isn't very good at handing out full solutions; we tend to help with specific problems.

Is the [EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider quick-start guide](https://github.com/mcintyre321/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider) enough to help you?

> A custom VirtualPathProvider for IIS - load views and assets from Embedded Resources in referenced assemblies . To get started, install into your ASP.NET web application via nuget:
>
> `Install-Package EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider`
>
> This will add some code into App_Start registering the provider.
>
> Move views and assets into other assemblies, maintaining folder structure. e.g.
>
> `/MyAspNetApp/Views/Thing/Thing.cshtml -> /ThingComponent/Views/Thing/Thing.cshtml`
>
> And set the the files BuildAction as EmbbeddedResource. Make sure your assembly is referenced, and you're done!
>
> By default, all assemblies in the appdomain are scanned. You can restrict this in `App_Start\RegisterVirtualPathProvider.cs` file. You can also map assemblies to their location on disk, so they [can be] refereshed when you edit the files during development.